# How can I have a gradient background with a solid colour behind it that extends to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

I've tried to do this various different ways, but have had no success so far.

Essentially what I want is a gradient going down the page (which I am using a background image for), then once the image ends, I want a background colour to take over (so that the page doesn't just turn white).

I've tried messing around with using different div tags and the like to layer things etc, but have had no luck so far. Either the background colour overrides the image, or the colour doesn't extend to the bottom of the page.

Comment: You probably want to set it to html or body in your css. Do you have any css code to share?

Comment: This is the code i've been using:
`body {
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 background-image: url(backgrou.png) !important;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-color: #ff7f2a;
}`

However the colour just overrides the image.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a background for your body:

```
body {
   /* Your gradient image */
   background-image: url(my_gradient.png);
   /* Color below the background image */
   background-color: #C0FFEE;
   /* Only repeat from left to right */
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Or use the background shorthand

```
body {
   background:#C0FFEE url('my_gradient.png') repeat-x left top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
body
{
  background: #FFCC00 url('your-background.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUKeT/

```
body{
  background: blue url(http://www.laserasecroydon.com/assets/images/blue-gradient.jpg) no-repeat fixed left top;
}
```

It's not pretty, but this way you can see where the color should take over

Answer (score 1):

```
body{    
background:url("image.jpg") #COLOR no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, I've worked it out. The CSS I was using was fine, it was the image that was the problem. Instead of setting the background to white, it was transparent. Hence the colour came through and overrode the gradient. I've now set the background to white, and it works fine.